# Microsoft Office 2016 Issue with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

Facing a strange issue with Microsoft Office 2016 on Windows 10

Laptop - http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/latitude-e5470-laptop/pd

Office was working fine up until yesterday, then out of nowhere it wouldn't open.

1. No Windows updates were installed
2. No third party software was installed
3. From what I can tell there were no Office updates

First I got the error "This app can't run on your PC"

When trying to run the program as Admin I get "Windows cannot Find C:\location\of\outlook.exe" but all the files it needs are where it is looking.

the event logs don't show me much, they're similar to the error above.

```
    **Error One**

    Activation of app 
    microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!ppleae38af2e007f4358a809ac99a64a67c1 
    failed with error: The application cannot be started. 
    Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem. 
    See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

    Error Two

    Intel(R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework : ESIF(8.1.10605.221)       
    TYPE: ERROR FUNC: rsrc_file_extract_resource_file FILE: rsrc_file.c       
    LINE: 384 TIME: 40578 ms

    Error: Unable to create resource file.
```

I noted error two above as I know that is an issue related to windows updates, but non were installed / pending so i'm not sure why it's there.

I've tried the "quick repair" and "online repair" neither were successful, I've uninstalled office and i'm currently running Microsoft ms office cleanup tool to make sure there's no traces left.

I'm confident after re-installing Office this time it will work but I still don't know why this happened in the first place.

So my question, is this a known issue with MS Office and windows 10, According to their "known issues" section it isn't, and I haven't found much online to help me troubleshoot the issue.

Have any of you dealt with an issue like this before? where an app will just stop working one day with no clear indication as of why.

**Edit One:**

To my surprise after fully removing and re installing office it is still not working.

[image]

Which leads me to this article - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_win10/not-able-to-install-office-365says-error-30015-11/3e731edb-fb62-492f-9618-01a16dbfe5c0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to the above was -

- Leave the Domain
- Log in as Local Admin
- Uninstall Office
- Reboot
- Run the [office removal tool](http://techdows.com/2015/10/download-microsoft-office-2016-fix-it-tool.html)
- Reboot
- Install office using the offline installer.

Painful but it works.