# Microsoft Office - Bad Image Error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

Opened a previous question about MS Office, it may or may not be connected but here it is - [Microsoft Office 2016 Issue with Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1174415/microsoft-office-2016-issue-with-windows-10/1191604#1191604)

**New issue:**

Currently there are 8 Laptops affected by this issue and they were all affected at different times,

> **One on Monday - Two on Tuesday - One on Wednesday -  4 on Thursday**
>
> 7 Dell Latitude E5470
>
> 1 Dell Desktop

**Error:**
[image]

Each office application has been affected by this and shows the exact same error when you try to open them.

One user told us that they updated office just before it happened which points to that.

Although, i spent two hours getting re-directed through Microsoft deep support tree to eventually be told there where no updates pushed to office.

So on the off chance that it isn't an update from Microsoft causing the issue i'm posting this here.

**What I have tried:**

1. Quick Repair - Did nothing
2. Full Online Repaird - Did nothing
3. Uninstall / Re-install - Did Nothing
4. Uninstall combined with Office Removal Tool - Did nothing
5. Full Clean install on Dell Desktop with no updates applied - Worked until reboot then gave the same error
6. Deleting / Renaming the "mso20win..." file - Doesn't work
7. Starting Outlook in safemode "Outlook /Safe" doesn't work
8. Everything mentioned in the linked question at the start.

At this point i'm lost and cannot find a solution online and office support have been no help so far, any ideas?

I may have left one or two things out that we've tried as to my knowledge it's everything so feel free to suggest anything.

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE:***

Recently after posting here another user has been affected by this error, bringing the total systems up to 9.

Just before he was hit with it he applied a Windows Update, there was a version build update so a fairly major one as well.

Unfortunately I cannot revert to a previous build version as windows isn't allowing me nor do I have time as he needs a solution asap, Will post results of a build version downgrade / re-install once I can get to a system.

Since the fresh install of win10 had the same issue, the iso must of been created using the latest build version if that's the cause.

Hopefully it'll be good news in the next update.

**Update Two**

Another system affected this morning, this was a brand new system that was only Setup one week ago, and I blocked windows updates on it, therefore, the above theory of windows updates causing the issue is out the window.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file returning the Error?  I found something on [Microsoft's Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/234a7557-3318-4d32-bc4b-8e6fd60ceaad/bad-image-error-on-microsoft-office-files-and-the-application-itself?forum=officeitproprevious) that seems to help some.  (Method A)  Renaming the file could force Office to recreate it from scratch, which might fix your problem.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I have, i also tried deleting the associated files hoping microsoft office would recreate them like it does with .pst files, i'll add that above, thanks

Comment: @CheesusCrust Just to add to the above comment, when deleting / renaming the file, office the wouldn't open at all.

Comment: If you [start Outlook using it's safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-can-t-start-Microsoft-Outlook-2016-2013-or-2010-or-receive-the-error-Cannot-start-Microsoft-Office-Outlook-Cannot-open-the-Outlook-Window-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85), does it work?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It doesn't unfortunately, same response to deleting / renaming the mso file, nothing happens when trying to launch it in safe mode - I've added that to the above as well, thanks,